# Separating command arguments from flags

Tags: shell, command-line, arguments

Say I have a command that takes flags and arguments, like this:

```
mycommand --foo bar arg1 arg2
```

(The `foo` flag has a value of `"bar"`.)

But what if the `foo` flag can optionally be supplied with no argument?

```
mycommand --foo arg1 arg2
```

How do I prevent `arg1` being considered the value for the `foo` flag?

Comment: I'm voting to move this question to [unix.se] since it's more about how unix works than about systems administration. In other words, the close vote currently on your question is not about actually closing but about moving.

Answer (score 7):

The most common used idiom in Unix to separate the command line flags from the rest of the arguments is to use a double dash (`--`).

If the utility uses the C library function `getopt()` (either directly or indirectly), the double dash will signal the end of the command line options, and `getopt()` will end its parsing of the command line.

This is from the [`getopt(3)` manual](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man3/getopt.3) on OpenBSD:

> The interpretation of options in the argument list may be cancelled by the option ‘--’ (double dash) which causes getopt() to signal the end of argument processing and return -1.

This is why the correct way to delete a file called `-f` is

```
$ rm -- -f
```

for example.

It is likely that your shell implements the built-in `getopts` command with a call to this library function.

IMHO, it's nice to know how to use `getopts` in shell scripts, and `getopt()` in C programs. It's not very difficult, and it makes life a lot easier when you write the command line parsing code of your project.

There is also a `getopt_long()` available in some C libraries, for parsing "long options" (`--option=value`). This, however, is an extension (no pun intended).

Answer (score 3):

Consider something like:

```
mycommand --foo=bar arg1 arg2
```

Requiring `=<someval>` when assigning a value to the flag would remove ambiguities.

It is clear this is a different case where the value is not specified:

```
mycommand --foo arg1 arg2
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no general answer to this. It depends entirely on how `mycommand` interprets its arguments. The ambiguity would be removed, e.g., if `mycommand` only accepted a limited number of values for `foo` which can never occur as argument values, so an omitted `foo` value could be easily detected by checking if the next command-line parameter is an acceptable value for `foo` or not.