# Meaning of -- in set command in shell script

Tags: shell-script, set

What is the meaning of `set -- $PATH` in shell script?
Is this the same as `set` `echo "$PATH"` ?
What is the significance of `--` here?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/295492/30851

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate. The referenced thread states the usual usage of this arg. It does not answer this question precisely. The bash set command has a specific defined use for both -- and - : The -- unsets all existing positional arguments. The - signals the end of options to set, and the beginning of options to be changed in the shell as a whole.